# Cucumber with multithreading and reportportal

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, reportportal

I want to use  multithreading in my tests. Could you say me what is best practice to use it? I created 1 class for 1 thread.(so, today i have 8 test classes-) And i set count of forks in pom.xml profile properties.
it's ok or we can create a few threads in one class?
And another question about report portal:
How to use a few threads for one report in epam report portal?

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber JVM does not support parallel execution out of the box. Basically, you can try to utilize some maven surefire plugin ( or gradle analogue) to execute stories in parallel. If your tests run in JVM fork mode, you'll see multiple launches in ReportPortal since it's impossible to re-use one reporting session across multiple JVMs. 
So, the suggestion would be utilize maven surefire plugin and do not use JVM fork mode.